# How can I capture the keystroke that triggers "CellEndEdit" on a DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, keydown

I have a DataGridView that is set to EditOnF2.  I do some special processing of data in the CellEndEdit eventhandler that sets the value of the cell.  I still want the functionality of the EditOnKeystrokeOrF2 of reverting to the original value when the Esc key is pressed.  Unfortunately, at the CellEndEdit eventhandler, I don't see a way to tell what caused the CellEndEdit event to be fired.  I only want to change the value of the cell if the Esc key is not pressed.  How can I tell if it was or not?

Edit: It is worth noting that the KeyDown event does not get fired when the cell is being edited, nor for the final ending keystroke.

Edit2: I have tried the KeyPreview suggestion, but the form still does not capture the Escape key being pressed.

Edit3:  I've been experimenting with trying to get this working.  I originally posted some of the following as a separate post, but feel it might be more relevant to include it here.

I have a cell in a DataGridView that is now set to EditProgrammatically. To capture the keystroke that starts an edit, I am setting the cell.Value equal to the keystroke. However, this ruins the "Escape" functionality of the cell - when you press escape, instead of reverting to the original value, it reverts to the keystroke that I programmatically inserted into the cell.

I believe that if I could set the "EditedFormattedValue" on a cell, this would be where I want to put my keystroke value, however this appears to be read only. How can I accomplish what I am attempting?

An example to clarify: If the cell has a value of "54.3" in it, and I press the "9" key, it begins editing the cell and places a "9" there. If I hit Escape, instead of reverting to "54.3" it reverts to "9". What I want is for it to return to its original value of "54.3".

So, I am trying to tackle this issue from both the beginning and the end.  I think the real problem is that I am overwriting the original value and have no way to determine if I should revert it or not.

Edit4: It looks like CellValidating might be worth using, but I am seeing strange behavior when I experiment with it.  In a new project, I create the DataGridView and register for the various events and see that CellValidating is fired before the CellEndEdit.  However, in my project where I am trying to get this to work, CellEndEdit is firing BEFORE CellValidating.  Any ideas on what the difference might be?

Answer (score 2):

Set the [KeyPrevew property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) on your form to true; that will prevent the control from gobbling it up first. :)

Comment: Thanks, but after trying this, it looks like the escape key is still only being recognized by the cell as the end of the edit and not as an actual KeyDown or KeyPress event on the form.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're absolutely right, `KeyPreview` won't work. At first, I thought I could get around this by overriding the [IsInputKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isinputkey%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method of the form. This technique has worked for me in some other cases where I couldn't catch a key I needed to catch. That didn't work either, so I tried subclassing the `DataGridView` and overriding `IsInputKey` there. That didn't work either. After some digging through the other methods I could override, I learned there was another class of keys called command keys that I needed to intercept. To do that, override [ProcessCmdKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey.aspx) on your `DataGridView` (you'll need to subclass it).

Here is my code:

```
public class CommandKeyInterceptingDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(keyData);
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

And the output from entering edit mode with F2, modifying a cell to say "Hello" and canceling the edit with Escape.

```
F2
ShiftKey, Shift
H, Shift
E
L
L
O
Escape
```

Hopefully this gives you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was similar, Here is my workaround:

`Problem:` When user started editing a cell value in DGV and pressed ESC key before committing value EndEdit was being called, which re-wrote all the DGV fields to database thus updating the update date & time fields, i only wanted DGV.EndEdit to run when user actually changed value and did not press ESC while doing so.

`Solution:` In Cell Validation i used a flag like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899329/how-to-run-run-cellendedit-only-when-cell-valuechanged-in-datagridview/8899620#8899620) to check if value is changed and if flag value is false the just do a `if(!flag)return;` on EndEdit