# Update only the edited fields in a C# application

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, crud

I have a big table in my SQL Server database as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Servers](
[ServerId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[ServerName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[HostName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[OperatingSystem] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[OSVersion] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[OSComment] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[ServerManufacturer] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ServerModel] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[IP] [binary](4) NULL,
[Mask] [binary](4) NULL,
[Gateway] [binary](4) NULL,
[PrimaryDNS] [binary](4) NULL,
[SecondaryDNS] [binary](4) NULL,
[NetworkType] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[NetworkComment] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[SiteId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
[DataCenterRow] [smallint] NULL,
[DataCenterRack] [smallint] NULL,
[AntiVirusProduct] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[AntiVirusVersion] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[AntiVirusComment] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[PassedOSSecurity] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Approved] [bit] NULL,
    [ApprovedBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Servers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ServerId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

In my C# Windows Forms application I have a form that displays the contents of this table and performs Display/Create/Delete/Update operation.

Now when I edit certain fields in a record I need to performs a query that will update only the fields which has been updated. In other words, I need a query that will dynamically identify the edited fields and update them.

The stored procedure that updates the columns one by one looks like this:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateServer @ServerName nvarchar(50), @HostName nvarchar(50),@OperatingSystem nvarchar(50),
                               @OSVersion nvarchar(50), @OSComment nvarchar(50),@ServerManufacturer nvarchar(50),
                               @ServerModel nvarchar(50), @IP nvarchar(15),@Mask nvarchar(15), @Gateway nvarchar(15), 
                               @PrimaryDNS nvarchar(15), @SecondaryDNS nvarchar(15), @NetworkType nvarchar(20),@NetworkComment nvarchar(200),
                               @SiteId uniqueidentifier, @DataCenterRow smallint, @DataCenterRack smallint, @AntiVirusProduct nvarchar(50),
                               @AntiVirusVersion nvarchar(50), @AntiVirusComment nvarchar(200), @PassedOSSecurity bit, @Approved bit,
                               @ApprovedBy nvarchar(50)
    AS
    UPDATE [SystemsInfo].[dbo].[Servers] 
    SET ServerName=@ServerName,HostName=@HostName,OperatingSystem=@OperatingSystem,OSVersion=@OSVersion,OSComment=@OSComment,ServerManufacturer=@ServerManufacturer,ServerModel=@ServerModel,IP=(select dbo.fnBinaryIPv4(@IP)),
           Mask=(select dbo.fnBinaryIPv4(@Mask)),Gateway=(select dbo.fnBinaryIPv4(@Gateway)),PrimaryDNS=(select dbo.fnBinaryIPv4(@PrimaryDNS)),SecondaryDNS=(select dbo.fnBinaryIPv4(@SecondaryDNS)),
NetworkType=@NetworkType,NetworkComment=@NetworkComment,SiteId=@SiteId, 
    DataCenterRow=@DataCenterRow, DataCenterRack=@DataCenterRack, AntiVirusProduct=@AntiVirusProduct, AntiVirusVersion=@AntiVirusVersion, AntiVirusComment=@AntiVirusComment, PassedOSSecurity=@PassedOSSecurity,
               Approved=@Approved,ApprovedBy=@ApprovedBy;
```

Comment: are you using linq to sql or sqlclient?

Comment: sqlclient, I invoke a stored procedure in order to perform the query.

Comment: You have a GridView holding all these records? And you want your application to automatically generate a query that updates all the updated fields in your application?

Comment: Yes, but only the updated fields not all of them

Comment: If you have a stored procedure to update the records how do you manage to pass only the updated data? This is a key point to solve your problem. Can you show the code of this stored procedure?

Comment: Did not manage it yet, my initial idea is that I will send two arrays, one arrays for the columns names and the other for their values. Would it be easier if I used another alternative than stored procedures?

Comment: The whole point of submitting only changed values is pointless here. You are forced to write a lot of customized code and for what? If you submit an appropriate query text with parameters the database engine will parse your query one time and store its query plan in its cache and reuse it in subsequent calls, instead if you pass everytime a different query with different parameters the database engine cannot optimize easily your code and the end result is probably less optimal performances. I cannot recommend to use this approach with your actual table (not really big)

Comment: However if you still wants to work in that way I can only suggest to look at the [DataRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135373(v=vs.110).aspx) class (where a collection of these objects is the Rows property of the DataTable class) When you try to read a DataRow value (a field) you can use an overload that takes an DataRowVersion enum flag. Asking for DataRowVersion.Original returns the initial value of the field while DataRowVersion.Current is the actual, edited or not value of the field. Its your job to find the differences and write the dynamic stored procedure.

Comment: Don't go that road. You will spend time and effort to gain nothing. In a real world example you will notice that there is no difference in either way, but the work you have to do is pretty much. Listen to @Steve.

Comment: So, I should write an update statement that updates all the columns in the tables and sets the changed columns with the new values while settings the unchanged columns with the same old values. @Steve, thanks for the info on DataRow class very insightful.

Comment: Or use an ORM that takes these details away from your code. ([Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/) is the big one but look also at how the smaller and speedier [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) works)

Comment: @Steve you are completely right, what you think about the idea in my answer?

Comment: Well there are many ways to kill the cat. You can keep yourself a copy of the original values and compare. But still the point is: _All this work is basically useless_ I experienced only one situation where this _checking_ was needed. It was a financial project where every single change made required a log entry in another table with the changes and the user that changed the record. But that has been resolved a lot more efficiently using Triggers in the database engine

Comment: When I started developing software decades ago I was surprised, coming from a database background, that apps updated every column on each write even when a single piece of data changed, However, to do otherwise is fiendishly complicated, prone to errors and a time sink. I second Steve's recommendations, Dapper is v good.

Answer (score 0):

I think the comment provided by Steve is the main way.

But, another option is to track the fields edited by user in your UI (eg. [CellEndEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15427727/2803565) or [CellValueChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8899620/2803565)), and **create the dynamic sql query in your c#** code (using a `StringBuilder` and `SqlParameters`) and finally execute it.